# linux + how to set auto-negotiation: No from Linux machine side

Tags: linux, networking, redhat-enterprise-linux

we have the following NIC configuration. from ethtool , ( the server is RHEL 7.9 version )

```
ethtool p1p1
Settings for p1p1:
        Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   10000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: No
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 10000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: FIBRE
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: off
        Supports Wake-on: d
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

we try to set auto-negotiation to **yes** by adding the following line to **ifcfg-p1p1** file and restart the network service but without success.

```
ETHTOOL_OPTS="speed 10000 duplex full autoneg on"
```

the second try was with the following.

```
ethtool -s p1p1 autoneg  on speed 10000 duplex full
Cannot set new settings: Invalid argument
  not setting speed
  not setting duplex
  not setting autoneg
```

but without success

what are the other options in order to set auto-negotiation: Yes ?

or maybe this is something that related to cisco switches and can't configured from Linux side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This 10000baseT device does not allow auto-negotiation as you can see from your output.

It only operates at 10Gbps/full.

No fibre 10Gbps device allow auto-negotiation.

From the wikipedia entry...

`It was first defined by the IEEE 802.3ae-2002 standard. Unlike previous Ethernet standards, 10GbE defines only full-duplex point-to-point links which are generally connected by network switches; shared-medium CSMA/CD operation has not been carried over from the previous generations of Ethernet standards[1] so half-duplex operation and repeater hubs do not exist in 10GbE.`

Comment: It looks like OP has a twisted-pair Ethernet module inserted, though; don't those still perform autonegotiation?

Comment: @u1686_grawity `Port: FIBRE` I cannot see anything in the post to suggest it is anything but a fibre module. See my updated answer.

Comment: Well, the `T` in `10000baseT` stands for "Twisted pair"... as opposed to X/CR/SR for fiber.